# Is it possible to use any function for declare the path in express js get routing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, express

Actually, I want to create a web app in node js but when I used to special characters in my navigation path which I wanna go it shows "Cannot get /contest' ". So I want to try a function for sanitizing the path, remove the special characters from my URL and return actual path. How can it be possible in express js to get routing?

Comment: You need to explain a bit more about what you're trying to do and perhaps show us the actual URL you want to use.  HTTP has an [encoding specification](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm) that allow you to embed special characters in URLs by escaping them.  And, since it appears you may be knew here, questions are nearly always better if you show us a specific example of what you're trying to do rather than ask just a generic question.  Then, you can get answers that show you exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Express for Node supports regular expressions in [routes](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

There is also Router Tester available for you [here](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/).